# How to perform this printing in for loop?

Tags: python, list

Now I have,

`en = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

If I use normal for loop, the coming result will like that,

```
for i in en:
  print i

1
2
3
4
5
6
```

But I want to perform like this:

```
12
34
56
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and slices

```
>>> for i,j in zip(en[::2],en[1::2]):
...    print("{}{}".format(i,j))
... 
12
34
56
```

---

As [Steven Rumbalski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322401/steven-rumbalski) mentions in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996645/how-to-perform-this-printing-in-for-loop/32996709?noredirect=1#comment53818359_32996709) you can also do

```
>>> it = iter(en)
>>> for i,j in zip(it, it):
...    print i,j
... 
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

`it` here is an iterator over the list. Hence it gives out the next value in the list whenever it's `next` method is called. Once the end is reached, it raises an exception (StopIteration) after which the iteration stops. The `zip` internally calls `next` of the iterator. Hence everytime it returns two adjacent values together, as you are calling the same object. In this way we can get the desired output.

Comment: `for i,j in zip(*([iter(en)]*2)):` would also work.  Or `it = iter(en);for i,j in zip(it, it):`.

Comment: @Steve Added it. Do have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,len(en),2):
    print str(en[i])+str(en[i+1])
```